# Floyd algorithm implemented with (const vector<int>& t : flights), what are the values stored on 't'

Tags: c++, vector

I came across this implementation of floyd, but i have a question as to what 't' stores as values, seeing that flights is a vector of vectors. (I understand how the algorithm works.)

```
//vector<vector<int>>& flights
//vector<vector<int>> vec(n, vector<int>(k + 1));

for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        vec[j][i] = vec[j][i - 1];

        for (const vector<int>& t : flights)
        {
            vec[t[1]][i] = min(vec[t[1]][i], vec[t[0]][i - 1] + t[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is a range-based loop, introduced in C++11.  Here, `t` is just a const reference to an element of `flights`.  The loop will visit each element of `flights` in order, and you can use the identifier `t` to reference the current element.

The loop is roughly equivalent to the following pre-C++11 syntax:

```
for(std::vector<std::vector<int>>::const_iterator it = flights.begin(); it != flights.end(); ++it)
{
    const vector<int>& t = *it;
    vec[t[1]][i] = min(vec[t[1]][i], vec[t[0]][i - 1] + t[2]);
}
```